# Show 4 different posts in Wordpress using loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php code in my Wordpress news site which will show 4 different posts from 2 categories News and Events at a time in a container. But my current code shows only one post of one category 4 times although there are 4 posts in news and events category. I want to show 4 different posts from news and events in the container instead of 1 post shown 4 times that is happening now.
Here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="dc-news-trend">
                        <?php
                            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category' =>'50,52', 'orderby'=>'date','orer'=>'DESC');
                            $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
                            foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
                              setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="row margin-top-1">  
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="dc-news-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                <p class="dc-news-date">
                                                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                </p>    
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                                <div class="row margin-top-1">  
                                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="dc-news-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                        <p class="dc-news-date">
                                                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                        </p>    
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                                <div class="row margin-top-1">  
                                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="dc-news-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                        <p class="dc-news-date">
                                                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                        </p>    
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                                <div class="row margin-top-1">  
                                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="dc-news-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                        <p class="dc-news-date">
                                                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                        </p>    
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php endforeach; 
                                    wp_reset_postdata(); 
                                ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your query args use cat=>'50,52' not category=>.... :

```
<div class="dc-news-trend">
  <div class="row"> // I suppose you don't want new row for each post so we take it out from the loop
          <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array( 
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'cat' => '50,52',
              'posts_per_page' => 4,  
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'orer' => 'DESC'
            );

           $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
           foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
           //now we are inside foreach  loop so we need to output div with the content just 1 time (for each returned post)
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
              <div class="row margin-top-1">  
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6">
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="dc-news-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                     <p class="dc-news-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>    
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
         <?php endforeach; 
               wp_reset_postdata(); 
         ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will return posts that have these categories. Check the [query args](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in the WP documentation.

Comment: did you setup global $post; ? I see its missing in your code ?

Comment: how can I set it up? I am new to php and Wordpress

Comment: just check the edited answer, define it at the beginning of the php before the args

Comment: hmmmm, try then wir         'category__in' => array( 50, 52 ),   instead of 'cat' => ...

Comment: in general is there any reason for you to use get_posts() instead of WP_Query() ?

Comment: does not work either with 'category__in' => array( 50, 52 ),
same result as before

Comment: so you get just 1 post back, what is the category this post is in ?

Comment: There are 2 categories News and Events. Now it is showing one post 4 times in a div and showing all the other posts in several divs as the first one like a loop, its like the duplicate of the first div but with different post each time. But I want to show 4 different posts from both the categories in that first single div.

Comment: but of course, I didn;t even look at the full code.... what you are doing right now is thatyou're outputting each post 4 times ... I want just to know if the rest of the posts are the ones you need to get back from these 2 categories. Ill edit my answer now

Comment: yes now I need to show posts from 2 categories in one place so like in a div two posts from News category and other 2 posts from Events category. 4 of them are different posts. But now its one post showing 4 times in one div and there are 4 divs like that. I just want one div to show 4 different posts from 2 different categories.

Comment: I was stuck on the query and didn't realize you're actually outputting 4 times the divs with the content

Comment: ok, could you please write down the correct code to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: thanks a lot. its working fine. you are a life saver mate.